# php preg_match_all key value pair

Tags: regex, parsing, preg-match

> [[[begin]]]
>   [[[mapid]]]1994
>   [[[price]]]15000
>   [[[cate1]]]TOP
>   [[[maker]]]
>   [[[origi]]]
>   [[[modig]]]N
>   [[[ftend]]]
>   
>   [[[begin]]]
>   [[[mapid]]]1994
>   [[[price]]]15000
>   [[[cate1]]]TOP2
>   [[[maker]]]
>   [[[origi]]]
>   [[[modig]]]N
>   [[[ftend]]]
>   ...

here is multiple data template.

is this time, i want key-value pair result, use preg_match

```
$pattern .= "(?P<mapid>[[[pname]]](.*?))";
$pattern .= "[[[price]]](.*?)";
...
```

is result

```
[mapid] => [0] => [[[mapid]]]175741
```

but, i want result below,

```
[mapid] => [0] => 175741
```

additionally, when i want price not exist,

```
$pattern .= "(?P<mapid>[[[pname]]](.*?))";
$pattern .= "?([[[price]]](.*?))";
```

not working...

What should I do to get the results I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?P<mapid>(?<=\[\[\[price\]\]\]).*)
```

try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/47

Comment: Don't need to use look-behind: `\[\[\[price\]\]\](?P<mapid>.*)`